# Navigation in nested list with arrow keys ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I trying to make navigation in sidebar by arrow-keys, but have some problems. I tried to make it with pure javaScript with NextElementSibling and PreviousElementSibling, but nested elements are not sibling for root elements. How to do this correctly ? Below I passed link to sandbox, may be someone have an solution. Thank u!
https://codesandbox.io/s/pw3l6y542x?fontsize=14

Comment: What is wrong with your solution? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @felixmosh, I trying to make keyboard navigation by this list. You can try to focus the first element and pass Tab / Shift + Tab. I want to make the same, but with ArrowDown / ArrowUp...its some like TreeView

Comment: One trick that you can do, is let the browser handle the focus, you just need to proxy up key press to trigger 'shift-tab' on the focused element, and the browser will do the rest :]
The same thing with down -> tab press

Comment: @felixmosh thank u, i will try to do this, do you have any idea how to do this ? :)